# How to rename multiple folders at once to remove certain characters?

Tags: rename

How can I rename all these folders at once to remove "-v4"?

My directories look like this:

```
drawable-hdpi-v4/
drawable-ldrtl-v4/
mipmap-mdpi-v4/
```

Comment: (1) What do you mean by “at once”?  Generally, only one disk operation can happen at a time.  (We could split hairs and talk about concurrent operations on a RAID, but that’s beyond the scope of this question.)  (2) If you mean that you want to type a command to rename all your folders (one at a time), that’s fairly easy.  What research have you done?  What have you learned?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  (3) Please don’t post pictures of text.

Comment: Sorry, i m new to forum, what i mean is that i want to edit the name of the folders,  there is -v4 at the end of the name of many folders,  so i m looking for something like renaming loop that can remove -v4 from their names

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`, `dash`, `zsh` and maybe other shells with parameter expansion and assuming that only directories end with suffix `-v4`, you could do :

```
for i in *-v4; do mv "$i" "${i%-v4}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Install DoubleCommander (`doublecmd`). It has a group rename feature (`Ctrl+M`). https://doublecmd.github.io/doc/en/help.html
If you have installed Thunar  - http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/bulk_renaming_thunar/

Comment: Seconded on the group renaming feature of Thunar, it's excellent and even has regex support.  Another great standalone (graphical) option I use is pyrenamer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, we can remove the suffixing 3 characters using below code

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*-v4' -type d -execdir bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%???}"'  mover {} \;
```

Comment: Even if the OP assures us that *every* directory in their directory has a name ending with ``-v4`` (whether the question says this is debatable), prudence dictates the use of ``-name '*-v4'``.

Comment: I wonder why this answer was downvoted.   OK, yes (arguably), Freddy’s answer is a bit more streamlined (shorter and more efficient).   But, as far as I can see, msp9011’s answer works correctly, and it was posted earlier.   And yes, this answer is basically just a command with very little explanation — but so is Freddy’s.

Answer (score -1):

Use `find` with `xargs` commands:

```bsh
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*-v4' -print0 | \
  xargs -0 -I % bash -c 'mv -v "%" "$(echo % | sed "s/-v4$//")"'
```

`find` - search for files in a directory hierarchy

`xarg` - executes a command (`bash` here) with argument from `find`

`echo % | sed "s/-v4//"` - removes `-v4` from file name

Comment: (1) And what if there is a directory with the name `foo-v4bar-v4`? (2) It’s ironic that you know about ``find … -print0`` and `xargs -0`, but you build a shell command that fails for filenames with spaces and other special characters.

Comment: @G-Man it's really strange that I know about these commands, it was hard to find;) if you look closer to question, you may find that it's about Android resource directory layout, where all directories are following special convention, in a few words you can't put multiple `-v4` suffixes and can put it only in the end, and you can't put whitespaces or special characters in names. So my command will remove `-v4` for any valid android resource directory.

Comment: (1) Hard to find?  Users of Unix&Linux Stack Exchange write about the commands frequently, and there’s lots of documentation for them.  (2) I’ve looked at the question, and I don’t see any reference to Android.  It’s a Unix&Linux question on the Unix&Linux site, so it should be treated as a Unix&Linux question.  (3) And if you’re so sure that filenames won’t contain whitespace or special characters, why did you use ``find … -print0`` and ``xargs -0`` in the first place?